# Changing Home Directory for cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I know that this question has been asked before on this site, but I am very new with Cygwin and am really confused by a lot of the other answers.

What is the best method to change my home directory in Cygwin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the most easier way is to make a folder junction with `mklink.exe` windows command. Assuming that you would like to use windows home directory:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `cmd`.
2. rename your cygwin home e.g.: `c:\cygwin\home\username --> username_backup`
3. type `mklink /j c:\cygwin\home\username c:\Users\username`
4. if you would like to use the contents of your old home directory you should copy them to the new one